# Is there a way to delete a range of cells in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, range

Wondering of there is an equivalent to deleteRow(s), or deleteColumn(s) that would delete a range of cells - say B3:B10?  I would think that if it's possible to do it "manually", (as in highlight the range, right-click, select "Delete Cells" and Shift up), it would/should be possible to accomplish the same thing via script.  However, I have not seen anything.  It could be similar to getRange(), but call it deleteRange(starting row, starting column, ending row, ending column, parameter for up [1], left[2], right[3], or down[4]).  Something like that.  No?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  Just recorded a macros, and this is what came to be.  Seems to work like a charm.

```
function DeleteCellRange() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B4:G4').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B4:G4').deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
};
```